# PHP, MySQL - only getting the last entry

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to adjust an existing Web application, which i didn't programm. This is of the it's functionalities which the user using this Web App aren't satisfied with. So far i've managed to do what it's supposed to do, but my problem is that when i add new customer with the number bellow and try to edit an old entry i only get the last entry which has been added. I've tried using $this. but i doesn't help. So my question is how can i get the php to look at the entry coresponding to the customer's id and not only looking at the last entry added.

```
//set the query and fetch data from it    
$resnew = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");
while ($dnew=mysql_fetch_assoc($resnew)) {
    $number = $d['number'];
    $auto_id = $d['auto_id'];
    $modell = $d['modell'];             
}

//set the other query to fetch data from it   
$reslevel=mysql_query("SELECT level FROM modells WHERE auto_id=$modell");
while ($dlevel=mysql_fetch_assoc($reslevel)) {
    $parameter="level";
    $$parameter=$dlevel["$parameter"];
}

?>          
<li> //Output
    <label><? echo $label ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" 
      name="<? echo $settings_id ?>_settings_one_rule" 
      maxlength="<? echo $lenght ?>" 
      class="textfeld" 
      style="width:<? echo $should_lenght ?>px;" 
      value="<? 
                if ($settings_id == 12) { 
                    echo "$number  . $level ; 
                } 
             ?>"
    >
</li>
```

Comment: You need to place your output lines _inside_ the loop...

Comment: Note that this code is potentially vulnerable to sql injections! the mysql_... functions are depricated since php 5.5 so you should consider rewriting the whole part...

Comment: how is it vulnerable @Michael. OP's code does not rely on user input. `SELECT * FROM orders`

Comment: @Akin: `SELECT level FROM modells WHERE auto_id=$modell` (which, despite an apparent typo between `$d` and `$dnew`, appears to come from `orders` table; who knows how that data originates)

Comment: @Akin Inclusion of $modell within the query allows scope for injection. Besides, the failings of PHP's mysql_ API are well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your logic at the moment:

- Read data part 1 into a variable *V*
- Read data part 2 into a variable *V*
- ...
- Read data part *n* into a variable *V*
- Print variable *V*

Clearly, you're only going to get the last part.

**Move your output *inside* the loop.**

Then your logic will be:

- Read data part 1 into a variable *V*
- Print variable *V*
- Read data part 2 into a variable *V*
- Print variable *V*
- ...
- Read data part *n* into a variable *V*
- Print variable *V*

Comment: @John: That's not what I told you to do, and I can't quite comprehend why you think that'll have the expected outcome. Step through your program with a pencil and some paper, and trace how it is executed line by line. Think about when variables are set, and think about whether they're set when you want them to be.

Comment: @JohnDoe: There is no such thing as an "`if` loop".

Comment: As my 1st comment on your answer states. I've only posted the relevant part of the code the actual code for the whole Web App consists of 137 files each at least 500lines long.

Comment: @JohnDoe: And as the Help Centre states, you are supposed to post a [MCVE]. Clearly, you have not done that. I strongly suggest you improve your instruction-following skills.

Comment: @JohnDoe: No, you haven't.